# NSAttributedText alignment right and left doesn't work for the same object

Tags: ios, swift, nsattributedstring

I have a simple extension for `NSAttributedString`:

```
convenience init(
    string: String,
    strikeThrough: Bool = false,
    color: UIColor? = nil,
    font: UIFont? = nil,
    alignment: NSTextAlignment? = nil
) {
    var attributes = [NSAttributedString.Key: Any]()
    if strikeThrough {
        attributes[.strikethroughStyle] = NSUnderlineStyle.single.rawValue
    }
    if let color = color {
        attributes[.foregroundColor] = color
    }
    if let font = font {
        attributes[.font] = font
    }
    if let alignment = alignment {
        let style = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
        style.alignment = alignment
        attributes[.paragraphStyle] = style
    }
    self.init(string: string, attributes: attributes)
}
```

And this is how I use it in code:

```
        let baseString = "Collectives™ helps you find trusted answers faster, engage with product experts, and share knowledge around the technologies you use most."
        let baseColor: UIColor.mineShaft
        let baseFont = UIFont.poppinsRegular.withSize(16)
        let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: baseString, color: baseColor, font: baseFont)
        attributedString.append(NSAttributedString(string: "\n"))
        let color = baseColor.withAlphaComponent(0.5)
        let font = baseFont.withSize(12)
        let originalString = NSAttributedString(string: baseString, color: color, font: font, alignment: .right)
        attributedString.append(originalString)
```

And the results is the following:

[image]

Everything is left aligned. Why? The second part should be right aligned.

Comment: does alignment right work if you set it to all attributed strings ? perhaps some conflicting issue with your label/textfield and your attributed string?

Comment: when i run your code everything works as expected.The problem must be elsewhere

Comment: @OmerTekbiyik Hmm maybe... I return attributedText for `MessageKit` cell. Do you have an idea where ma be conflict?

Comment: I've never used messagekit unfortunately no

Comment: In `MessageKit`, there is a method `func paragraphStyle(for text:)` which I guess is called at some point (I didn't go further on the lib), to align elements to left or right depending on "who's" the author (yourself or another one). It override the paragraph value, and so the alignement. You customized the UI (it doesn't look like "Messages.app"), but I guess that method is still called. Put breakpoints in it to be sure, but that's my best guess, and since you didn't show specific code for the final use of your NSAttributedString. setting.

Comment: @Larme you are right. I couldn't find func you mentioned, but something really override my alignment. However I need to give it up, because it is not possible to use two alignments in one message.

Comment: It's in https://github.com/MessageKit/MessageKit/blob/master/Sources/Views/MessageLabel.swift

Answer (score 0):

I set two style for attributes and the result is ok, try to set like this:

```
let style = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
style.alignment = .left
    
let style2 = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
style2.alignment = .right
    
let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Collectives™ helps you find trusted answers faster, engage with product experts, and share knowledge around the technologies you use most.", attributes: [.paragraphStyle: style, .foregroundColor: UIColor.black, .font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14, weight: .bold)])
attributedString.append(NSAttributedString(string: "\nCollectives™ helps you find trusted answers faster, engage with product experts, and share knowledge around the technologies you use most.", attributes: [.paragraphStyle: style2, .foregroundColor: UIColor.gray, .font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12, weight: .semibold)]))
yourTextContainer.attributedText = attributedString
```

The result:

[image]